# Civi Price Sets

Tags: civievent, price-sets

For an upcoming event, we are requiring a security deposit that everyone must pay. How do I add that to the price set so that it's always there and the user does not have to do anything with it and cannot remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add price_set_field for the same in the price_set.

so, it remain always also make it as radio (mandate)

I guess this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add price field to a price set used for an event. You can navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> CiviEvents >> Manage Price Sets.

Look for the price set you used in the event and Click on 'View and Edit Price Fields' besides it. (Price set used for event can be checked under fee section of event configuration page.)
[image]

You will be redirected to list of Price fields in price set. Click on Add Price Field button and add price field of type radio with single option in it and make it as required.
[image]

Comment: cheerz!!!!!!!!!!